# Kendo Mobile-UI Navbar in Footer is not available in Android Skin

Tags: css, navbar, kendo-mobile

I changed the direction of the footer with the following code. The footer is now in the bottom of the page

```
<style>
    .km-android div.km-view {
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    }
    .km-android div.km-view {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    }

</style>
```

When I put a div with a data-role of navbar, it is not available in the android skin but visible in the iOS7 skin.

How can I make it available?

```
<div data-role="layout" data-id="recordDetailLayout">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#rightDrawer" data-icon="Add" style="border: 0" data-align="left"></a>

        </div>
    </header>

            <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#rightDrawer" data-icon="a"  style="border: 0"></a>
                    <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#rightDrawer" data-icon="b" style="border: 0"></a>
                    <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#rightDrawer" data-icon="c"  style="border: 0"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default View Title is hidden in Android, mostly due to the NavBar being at bottom. Check how to show it in our [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/mobile/navbar#showing-hidden-view-title).

Comment: thank you very much.. I checked this document before but thought that it is only for the title. Didn't know that it will show the hidden navbar also with no title.. thanks again.